# keras code runs with arbitrary number of class_weigths

Tags: r, keras

I'm ussing class_weights in Keras with R. The code runs fine, but I discovered a strange thing. I can give an arbitrary number of class_weights without getting an error.

My model classifies 9 classes so initially I fitted the model in this way

```
 model$fit( x= input_im, y= input_lab, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 1L , class_weight = c('0' = 1,'1' = 1,'2' = 1,'3' = 1,'4' = 1,'5' = 1,'6' = 1,'7' = 1, '8' = 1))
```

But I found that if I remove or add a classweight my code runs just as well.

```
model$fit( x= input_im, y= input_lab, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 1L , class_weight = c('0' = 1,'1' = 1,'2' = 1,'3' = 1,'4' = 1,'5' = 1,'6' = 1,'7' = 1) 

 model$fit( x= input_im, y= input_lab, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 1L , class_weight = c('0' = 1,'1' = 1,'2' = 1,'3' = 1,'4' = 1,'5' = 1,'6' = 1,'7' = 1, '8' = 1, '9' = 1))
```

both work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The class_weights are simply there to tell the model which class is "most important"
If you exclude one of them it simply has a default weight instead.

Seeing as all your weights are 1, you can just remove the class_weight parameter, as it does not do anything.

from the documentation:

> Optional named list mapping indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

Comment: The all 1 is just for testing I want to change them further on. So what you are saying is that if I add more weigths than there are classes it just ignores the weights and if I provide too few classes it simply assigns the default class.

Comment: you may get an error if you add to many weights, other than that, I think you are correct.